# Where can I find a widget to enable or disable GPRS in my Spice Mi-270 Android handset?

Tags: settings, internet, app-widgets, gprs

I have a Spice Mi-270 Android phone. There is no touch gadget to enable or disable the GPRS connection. Every time I have to select `settings -> wireless & networks -> data communication sim` and have to select a SIM to turn GPRS off.

How can I do this in one touch?

Answer (score 3):

[Widgetsoid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jim2&hl=en) will allow a user to create a bar of toggles - add the MOBILE DATA toggle in the network section. Then tapping that will toggle the data connection.

Of course - [a search](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=data%20toggle%20widget) turned up many other dedicated options. Try and use whichever you like best.

Answer (score 0):

Download [Go launcher EX](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gau.go.launcherex&hl=en) and install it and then download the Go widget called [Go Switch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gau.go.launcherex.gowidget.switchwidget#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDIxMiwiY29tLmdhdS5nby5sYXVuY2hlcmV4Lmdvd2lkZ2V0LnN3aXRjaHdpZGdldCJd) widget. This widget will allow you to switch among many apps through one touch very easily.